# How do you create a route to a specific show item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like 'about' to route to 'abouts/1'

I tried this:

```
match 'about' => 'abouts#show/1', :via => get
```

and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: don't use `abouts/1`. that route isn't descriptive. use `match 'about/:type'` to get routes like `about/cats`,`about/beer`.

Comment: It depends on what your end goal is. The fact you've called it 'abouts' suggests that it should potentially be a resource (ie. abouts/1, abouts/32...) but without some more information it's hard to tell.

If you wanted to do it as outlined, I'd say @maro has an effective method.

The real question is what are you trying to do here?

Comment: What is the name of your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
match 'about' => 'abouts#show', :via => :get, :defaults => {:id => 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about just removing the 1 from the route and retrieve the record you want directly in the controller method?

```
# routes.rb
match 'about' => 'abouts#show', :via => get

# abouts_controller.rb
def show
  @about = About.find(1)
end
```